# Is it true that $RP^3$ minus a point deformation retracts to a space homeomorphic to $RP^2$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have the following question:

> Is it true that $RP^3$ minus a point deformation retracts to a space
>   homeomorphic to $RP^2$

**My Efforts**

Answer is NO

Assume on the contrary that $RP^3$ with a point deleted deformation retracts onto a space homeomorphic to $RP^2$. It implies that fundamental group of $RP^3$ minus a point is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Deleting a point from $RP^3$ is same as removing $2$ points from $S^3$. By stereographic projection $S^3$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. As $R^3$ minus a point is simply connected, it's fundamental group  is trivial. So we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: "Deleting a point from $RP^3$ is same as removing $2$ points from $S^3$." This seems a bit shady, as you never "quotient back" into projective space to see what happens there. For instance, $\Bbb RP^3$ has an element of order $2$ in its fundamental group, while $S^3$ does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Assume you have removed $[0,0,0,1]$. Consider the map defined by $f_u([x,y,z,t])=([x,y,z,tu]), u\in [0,1]$.

Comment: I am not able to follow it completely:   What I can deduce from the above hint is that $f_0: RP^3\rightarrow RP^3$ sends $[x,y,z,t] \rightarrow [x,y,z,0]$. So we have a homotopy between Identity map and $f_0$. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, and $\{[x,y,z,0]\}\subset RP^3$ is $RP^2$.

Comment: I think  if I replace $u$ by $1-u$  then by the definition  of deformation retraction in Hatcher, at time $u=0$ everything is fixed. At time $u=1$ everything is moved into  $RP^2$ and for all time $u$ points of $RP^2$ are not moved. So we have found a deformation retract of $RP^3$ onto  $RP^2$

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb R\mathrm P^3$ has a CW structure given by attaching a $3$-cell to $\mathbb R\mathrm P^2$.  We can arrange for the puncture to be within the interior of the $3$-cell, and a punctured $3$-cell deformation retracts onto its boundary.

Comment: But why we can always arrange for the puncture to be within the interior of the $3-$ cell.

Comment: By a projective transformation: $\mathbb R\mathrm P^3$ is the collection of 1d vector spaces in $\mathbb R^4$, so rotate the cell decomposition using an element of $SO(4)$.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail.

Comment: An $n$-cell is a map $D^n\to \mathbb R \mathrm P^3$ with additional properties.  An orthogonal transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$  sends lines to lines, so descends to a homeomorphism $T':\mathbb R\mathrm P^3\to\mathbb R\mathrm P^3$.  The composition $D^n\to\mathbb R\mathrm P^3\xrightarrow{T'} \mathbb R\mathrm P^3$ gives a new cell, and if you do this to all the cells, you get a new CW structure.  Choose a $T$ which sends an interior point to the puncture point.